# Does a football player receive gold medal for UEFA Super cup win, and is he considered to be a winner, if not part of the match squad?

Tags: football, awards, uefa

Does [Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo) receive gold medal for [UEFA Super cup 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_UEFA_Super_Cup) and is he considered to be a winner, if not part of the match squad?

Comment: The case of CR7 and 2016 UEFA Supercup is also being discussed on [the talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Cristiano_Ronaldo#Super_Cup_2016) of his Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Lipata [This answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/17549/13485) applies to this question if you look at Super Cup regulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to official UEFA Super Cup regulations for the period 2015-18 (link [here](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/24/06/02/2240602_DOWNLOAD.pdf)) article 9.04, 40 gold medals are awarded to the winning team. And it's not mentioned that only players who are in the match squad should receive a gold medal. Thus Cristiano Ronaldo could receive a gold medal.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, it's speculation.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe Cristiano Ronaldo could receive a medal when he wasn't even part of the substitutes. In most competitions you have to be at least part of the subtitutes, and in some competitions if you were always a substitute and you were never in the field, you don't receive a medal.

Cristiano Ronaldo's official page is not listing the UEFA Super Cup 2016 in his palmares.

http://www.cristianoronaldo.com/career

In the player list of the UEFA Super Cup 2016 in UEFA's official website, he isn't listed either.

http://www.uefa.com/uefasupercup/season=2016/matches/round=2000778/match=2019261/prematch/player-lists/index.html

So, he wasn't part of the startup team, he wasn't part of the substitutes, and he wasn't part of the whole list of players for the cup, there is no reason to believe he got one, because he couldn't even count as part of the "wining team" even when some fan websites are listing the cup among his trophies.

Comment: Yeah, but the team receives 40 gold medals, and as far as I understand it, the team decides how to distribute them. So for sure Real Madrid has given Ronaldo a gold medal. It seems UEFA doesn't have regulation on that distribution and it is up to the team. After all it's just a Super cup - something in between a friendly match a official one.

Comment: I sent that question to UEFA, so let's see what they will answer.

Comment: It's interesting, in another competition organized by UEFA (the UEFA Champions league) Bravo who was a substitute in almost all games but who never was in the startup team, he didnt get a gold medal. It seems the same body has very different rules for different competitions

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [official Real Madrid website](http://www.realmadrid.com/en/football/squad/cristiano-ronaldo-dos-santos), you would see he has 2 European Super Cup medals in his awards.

So, Ronaldo definitely received a gold medal.