# If Liverpool FC win the Champions League does that mean Coutinho wins it as well or if FC Barcelona win Champions league will Coutinho win it as well?

Tags: football, awards, champions-league, transfer

I mean anything is possible in football and I was reading an article about how Coutinho can help FCB in terms of [attacking football](http://www.skysports.com/football/news/12087/11199095/philippe-coutinho-can-fulfil-various-roles-for-barcelona-says-guillem-balague) etc.

When I saw

> With Coutinho ineligible to play in Europe for Barcelona this season, Balague says Valverde will use the rest of the domestic campaign to get him to speed in central midfield. Alongside Sergio Busquets, Ivan Rakitic and Paulinho, Coutinho will hone the defensive side of his game.

I did some research and found out since Coutinho already played for Liverpool in the UCL he cannot play under Barcelona.

So if Liverpool win Champions League would Coutinho have a Champions League medal under his belt and same with Barcelona or will it be neither and he misses out of Champions League if either team win it??

I mean he did help Liverpool and as far as UEFA are aware he already played for Liverpool and thus cannot play for Barca.

Comment: You can only win titles with the club you play for, even if you're ineligible to play.

Comment: I don't have sources on me, but you are considered the champion for the club you PLAYED on. You can't play in the same season for 2 clubs on Champions league. If you play on X and move to Y, if X wins you are the champion, if Y wins you are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UEFA Champions League regulations](https://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/46/71/38/2467138_DOWNLOAD.pdf) include a section on *Trophy and medals*, which has three subsections. The only part that directly speaks to medals is 11.03, saying that

> [t]he  winning  team  is  presented  with  40  gold  medals  and  the  runner-up  with  40 silver medals. Additional medals may not be produced.

There is no restriction on who these medals can be given to or where they might be placed (unlike the replica trophies).

None of the regulations dealing with registration of players under *VII Player Registration*) then prevent a player who joined a club but was not registered or fielded in a match from being given one of the medals.

In the absence of any further restriction or requirement from UEFA, it appears the decision of awarding medals to individuals is left to the winning or runner-up club.

Comment: This doesn't address the question though. One thing is being given the medal, the other is given the accolade of champion.

Comment: Unless clubs are going to hand them out to people with no associations to the winning club, they're the same thing.

Comment: You can give a Medal to the doctor who fixed your star player's leg in half the time it usually would take, at 90'+1, and that player scored the freekick that gave you the win. It doesn't mean that the doctor is the Champion

Comment: Given that the question asks about medals in particular, I do not see any validity in the criticism.

Comment: Question title does not. And two questions are made on the body

Comment: The title is not the question, it is a reference for finding the question only. Since this answers at least one question made in the question body, it does answer the question. Please make a valid criticism or write your own answer.

Answer (score -3):

There are two stages for **UEFA** Champions League: the group stage, and the knockout stage. Before each of these stages teams have to submit their team members list to UEFA.

In case of Coutinho, he played for Liverpool in group stage and he is going to play in Barcelona in knockout stage of the league. Every team in the knockout stage has to submit their new players list to UEFA after this January transfer window. Coutinho won't be listed in the player list that will be submitted by Liverpool and will be included in FC Barcelona squad for knockout stage. So there is no problem in that he can play the rest of matches for FC Barcelona in UEFA.

Currently he is a FC Barcelona player. It doesn't matter where he was at group stage, or in which team's list he was included earlier. It only matters where he plays while the team wins the league. So in this season if FC Barcelona wins the UEFA Champions league he also wins it.

Comment: This is not true as one player cannot play for two different teams on Champions League the same season. Coutinho cannot play (nor be registered) for Barcelona this season. In fact, you can check for yourself at uefa.com