# Where can football teams place their replica trophies?

Tags: football, awards

Following this [Question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17548/if-liverpool-fc-win-the-champions-league-does-that-mean-coutinho-wins-it-as-well/17549#17549), where Nij answered about the medals, that they can be placed where the club wants them, not like the replica trophies, I would like to know, where can the clubs place those trophies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered by the same section of regulations as that question, where article 11, section 11.02 states that

> [r]eplica  trophies  awarded  to  winners  of  the  competition  (past  and  current)  must remain  within  the  relevant  club’s  control  at  all  times  and  may  not  leave  the  club’s country  without  UEFA’s  prior  written  consent.  Clubs  must  not  permit  a  replica trophy  to  be  used  in  any  context  where  a  third  party  (including,  without  limitation, their  sponsors  and  other  commercial  partners)  is  granted  visibility  or  in  any  other way  which  could  lead  to  an  association  between  any  third  party  and  the  trophy and/or  the  competition.  Clubs  must  comply  with  any  trophy  use  guidelines  that the UEFA administration may issue from time to time.

In effect

- the real trophy will go where UEFA the organisation puts it
- the replica trophy must stay in the club's home country, unless they get permission to move it
- the replica trophy must not go anywhere that makes it appear some third  party, such as a business, has a relationship with the trophy or with the the championship
- UEFA will make further detailed rules for where and how to keep the trophy, but these are not apparently widely available